# Angular Unit Tests: TypeError: env.catchExceptions is not a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I wrote some unit tests for my Angular app, and they all pass when I run `ng test`, which is great. However, the test is still considered as not successful because of an error thrown at the end:

```
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  TypeError: env.catchExceptions is not a function
```

After some research, all I found is this [Github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-unit-testing-example/issues/79) saying to downgrade to jasmine 2.99, but it did not work for me.

I am using Angular 10, and testing with Jasmine and Karma.

Answer (score 2):

Following the github link, Changing the follow dev dependencies to these versions worked for me when I had the same error.

- "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
- "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
- "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
- "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
- "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
- "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",

[image: dev dependencies]

Comment: I'm having the same issue and noticed your versions are just like mine except I have `jasmine@3.6.3`.  Error I get seems to mention the html reporter and so I will play around with that.